# Add a div with cordinates given in another

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, position

I want to put a div in another with cordinates given by input text fields. The added span should be with relative positions to parent's cordinates. 
The problem is that it doens't add anything but yet it changes the position of the canvas.

```
<html>
 <head> 
<style> 
    #rectangle { position: relative; }
</style>
<body>  
    300 x 300 px MAX<br/>
    <canvas id="rectangle" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
    <br/> 
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td>Horizontal starting cordinate:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "x" value = ""/></td>
    </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td>Vertical starting cordinate:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "y"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Width of the rectangle:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "width"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Height of the rectangle:</td>
        <td><input type="text" id = "height"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="button" id = "draw" value = "Click"/></td>
    </tr> 
</table> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $("#draw").click(function(e){ 

        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

        var x1 = parseInt($("#x").val());
        var y1 = parseInt($("#y").val());
        var width = parseInt($("#width").val());
        var height = parseInt($("#height").val()); 

        $("#rectangle")
            .add("div")
            .css("id", "right-zone") 
            .css("z-index", "5")
            .css("position", "absolute")
            .css("left", x1)  
            .css("top", y2)  
            .css("width", width)
            .css("height", height)
            .css("background-color", "#FF0000")
            .css("border", "solid red 1px");
   }); 
})  
</script>
```

Any ideas what's wrong ?

Comment: could you provide a jsfiddle to see the example?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/qsFmf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few "bugs" in your code, both html and JS.

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kGd2G/1/

I.e. use `div` instead of `canvas`

```
<div id="rectangle" style="width: 300px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

To simplify JS, I used a "template div" to set some defaults for the rectangle that would be added.

Answer (score 4):

You should probably be using [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`.add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/). `.add()` will not add a div to the DOM, but an element to a set of matched elements.

**Edit:** on second thought, I see you are trying to append a div to a canvas element. You might be interested in checking [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-author-20110809/the-canvas-element.html), where it is stated:

> The contents of the canvas element, if any, are the element's fallback
>   content.

So you should probably replace your canvas element with a div. That, or edit your question to better reflect this detail.